# Text not displaying in a text/picture listview row

Tags: android

```
I have a listview row.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="26sp" 
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_weight="3"/>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It should be displaying a piece of text, and a picture. But it's only displaying the picture.

Comment: How are you setting the text for `text1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with using

something like this:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:background="#FFF"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/something"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              android:textSize="16sp"
              android:contentDescription=""
              android:text="something"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="#FFF"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:contentDescription=""
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
               android:src="@drawable/image"/>

</TableRow>
```

and maybe your LinearLayout is black same as TextView. Not sure, usually it works..

Comment: how to I get the text to sit on the far left, and the image to sit on the far right?

Comment: you can add android:gravity="left" on text view, and on image android:gravity="right" :D

Answer (score 0):

change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` of both `textview` and `imageview` to `android:layout_width="0dp"`